# How to insert single row in parent table and multiple rows in child table using single stored procedure SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have two tables:

The first one is `Requisitions` (parent table):

```
RequisitionId          int     // primary key
RequisitionNumber      varchar(20)
RequisitionBy          varchar(100)
Remarks                varchar(300)
ApprovedStatus         varchar(20)
```

Other one is `RequisitionDetails` (child table):

```
RequisitionDetailId    int     // primary key
RequisitionId          int     // foreign key ("Requisitions" table)
ProductId              int
UnitConversionId       int
Quantity               decimal(18, 2)
```

Now I want to insert one row into the `Requisitions` table and mutiple rows in `RequisitionDetails` table using a single stored procedure.

The stored procedure should contain `ROLLBACK` command if there is any problem in the transaction. I need help writing this stored procedure.

I've created stored procedure to insert one row in "Requisitions" table and I have the RequisitionId of the inserted row. Now using this RequisitionId how could I insert multiple row for RequisitionDetails table?

Here is the stored procedure. I need to extend it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertRequisition
(
    @RequisitionNumber varchar(20) = NULL,
    @RequisitionBy varchar(100) = NULL,
    @Remarks varchar(300) = NULL,
    @ApprovedStatus varchar(20) = NULL
)

AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @requisitionId INT;

    INSERT INTO [Requisitions] 
    (
        [RequisitionNumber],
        [RequisitionBy],
        [Remarks],
        [ApprovedStatus]
    )

    VALUES
    ( 
        @RequisitionNumber,
    @RequisitionBy,
        @Remarks,
        @ApprovedStatus
    )

    SET @requisitionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

   END
```

Comment: Have you even gotten started? Show us what you have so far! Where are you stuck? We'll help you get unstuck - but we won't just write the whole code for you ....

Comment: I need to insert multiple rows for "RequisitionDetails" using the "@requisitionId" and how could I able to insert other parameters for "RequisitionDetails" for multiple insert?

Comment: @raisul what is meaning of multiple rows. Is it fixed number of rows (2-3 rows) or you want to take refrence from some other table for inserting in RequisitionDetails

Comment: I think some more info is required for this question to be answered like from where ProductId, UnitConversionId and Quantity will populate, is these fields are extracted from any other table or you must sent them as well as parameter to stored proc...

Comment: @Pratik no of multiple rows is not fixed. Actually for "RequisitionDetails" table I am temporarily saving the data to a variable(it may contains single or multiple rows). Is it possible to pass that variable to stored procedure to insert data for "RequisitionDetails"?

Comment: Pranav, my confusion is here. ProductId, UnitConversionId and Quantity these are saved in a variable(it may contains single or multiple rows' data). Now how should I pass that variable to stored procedure?

Comment: @raisul If this variable is of `table type structure` then you can easily pass, if you know how to pass datatable to procedure try it or else let me know i will post in answer

Comment: @Pratik please show me a sample. I am new in stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood the problem correctly, below code should be able solve your problem.

**Step 1 :**  Create Type in Database

```
CREATE TYPE AnyNameTableType AS TABLE
(ColumnName1 INT, ColumnName2 VARCHAR(50))
```

**Step 2 :**   Create/Modify your Stored Procedure to accept table type

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE My_TestProc
 (@tvpVariableName AnyNameTableType READONLY)
 AS
 BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM @tvpVariableName;
   --You can use this variable as table anywhere you want
   --Select/Insert/Update from this table and update your RequisitionDetails
   --table.
 END;
```

**Step 3 :**   Write your c# code to pass this variable.

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable(); //Define your datatable simillar to TableType declared in SQL
    table.Columns.Add("ColumnName1"); //Same Column Name you should use as of TableTYpe
    table.Columns.Add("ColumnName2");
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row["ColumnName1"] = 1; //Fill you datatable with data you want
    row["ColumnName2"] = "Pratik";
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    table.AcceptChanges();

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("data source=yoursource;database=test;uid=sa;pwd=yourpwd");
    SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("My_TestProc", connection);
    selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter tvpParam = selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpVariableName", table);//Parameter Name
    tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;  // Very Important Not to miss
    connection.Open(); //You can add multiple parameters also.
    grid.DataSource = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    grid.DataBind();
    connection.Close();
```

After this steps if you have any confusion let me know.